# Google Captcha v3 works fine when putting script code in <script> tag but not works when putting in app.js of Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm

I am using Laravel 8.x, Google Captcha v3, Laravel Mix of Laravel/Ui - Auth Bootstrap

In `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
```

In `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" id="recaptcha-form">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary g-recaptcha" 
         data-sitekey="{{ env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY') }}" data-callback="onSubmit" 
         data-action="submit">
              {{ __('Login') }}
    </button>
</form>
```

The problem is: It works fine when I put script code directly in html files like this:

In `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`

```
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onSubmit(token) {
        document.getElementById("recaptcha-form").submit();
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

But when I put above script in js of Laravel Mix file `resources/js/app.js`, it seems not working and not showing any errors

```
require('./bootstrap');
...
function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("recaptcha-form").submit();
}
```

Of course I do command `npm run dev`